# Issue in adding Xsrf-Token in an Angular 6

Tags: php, angular, csrf, angular6, x-xsrf-token

Posting data from the form submit via API was successful.

But after adding X-CSRF-TOKEN to the header and setting  `withCredentials: true`
resulted data were not posted to the script named `insert.php`

**Error:**

> Failed to load http://localhost/simple_api/insert.php: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the
>   wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The
>   credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
>   controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Removing `withCredentials: true` resulted data were successfully posted.
But unable to see the X-CSRF-TOKEN

**app.module.ts**

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import {HttpClientModule, HttpClientXsrfModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import { UsrService } from './usr.service';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      RegisterComponent,
      LoginComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule,
      HttpModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
        cookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
        headerName: 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'
      })
    ],
    providers: [UsrService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

**user.services.ts**

```
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
addUser(info){
    console.log(info);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });
    console.log(options);
    return this._http.post("http://localhost/simple_api/insert.php",info, options)
      .pipe(map(()=>""));
  }
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-CSRF-Token, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
?>
```

[image]
Consoling the values of the header, Xsrf-Token was not set. How am I supposed to set the Xsrf-Token values?

---

### **UPDATE:**

```
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HttpClientXsrfModule} from "@angular/common/http";

constructor(private _http:HttpClient) { }

  addUser(info){
    console.log(info);
    // let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    // let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });
    // console.log(options);
    return this._http.post("http://localhost/simple_api/insert.php",info)
        .subscribe(
                data => {
                    console.log("POST Request is successful ", data);
                },
                error => {
                    console.log("Error", error);
                }
            ); 
  }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {HttpClientModule, HttpClientXsrfModule} from "@angular/common/http";

imports: [
    ...
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
      cookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      headerName: 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'
    })
  ],
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following header to your php code

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
```

Also, why are you mixing old `HttpModule` and new `HttpClient` module? `RequestOptions` and `Headers` are deprecated in angular 6

If you use `HttpClient`, content type is already set to json by default, and `withCredentials` is set by the `HttpClientXsrfModule`.

Your request can just be simplified to

```
 return this._http.post("http://localhost/simple_api/insert.php",info);
```

**Edit**
The default interceptor created behind the scene by `HttpClientXsrfModule` does not seem to handle absolute urls....

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18859

Comment: Good catch! But I'm still not able to set the 'XSRF-TOKEN'. Instead of `RequestOptions` and `Headers` what are the other methods needed to implement in order to set 'XSRF-TOKEN' Will you modify the above-updated post with code...

Comment: setting `header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");` in PHP worked. But unable to set XSRF-TOKEN in header

Answer (score 1):

Server-side, `XSRF-TOKEN` is not a *header*, but a **cookie** to set beforehand. This cookie should be sent from the server to the page in which your Angular app lives, that is, in the example below, the template 'some.template.html.twig' should load the Angular app.

This way Angular will add and send the correct X-XSRF-etc. header properly.

**Please note**: the cookie must be generated with the HttpOnly option set to ***FALSE***, otherwise Angular won't see it.

E.g. if you're using Symfony, in a controller action you could set a XSRF cookie as follows:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller
{
  /**
   * Disclaimer: all contents in Route(...) are example contents
   * @Route("some/route", name="my_route")
   * @param Request $request
   * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
   */
  public function someAction(Request $request, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrf)
  {
    $response = $this->render('some.template.html.twig');
    if(!$request->cookies->get('XSRF-TOKEN')){
      $xsrfCookie = new Cookie('XSRF-TOKEN',
        'A_Token_ID_of_your_Choice',
        time() + 3600, // expiration time 
        '/', // validity path of the cookie, relative to your server 
        null, // domain
        false, // secure: change it to true if you're on HTTPS
        false // httpOnly: Angular needs this to be false
      ); 
      $response->headers->setCookie($xsrfCookie);
    }

    return $response;
  }
}
```