# Security To Implement On Persist Cookie REST Api Website / Mobile Apps

Tags: html, asp.net, angular, rest, asp.net-web-api

So my current state is I have a REST API web server (ASP.Net Web API), a website in plain Html which communicates with the server via ajax / angular post and get, also I have a mobile application which communicates via ajax / angular post and get.

I use `Basic Auth header` to secure the request, the web server will decrypt the content of the auth header and do the verification after.

What kind of attacks would the system be vulnerable to? Also what kind of security  should I implement.

I read about the `CSRF` attacks and I think my system have no protection against it, but I have no idea how to implement it on REST API.

Also what about the cookie stealing attacks. Because my system uses persist cookies to store the auth token, how to deal with this kind of attack?

Comment: Have a look here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/166724/should-i-use-csrf-protection-on-rest-api-endpoints for your question regarding. Maybe your question should be moved to security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent CSRF attacks, both your backend (ASP.NET Web API) and frontend (Angular) must be configured to prevent such an attack.

Taken from https://angular.io/guide/security#xsrf:

> To prevent XSRF, the application must ensure that a user request originates from the real application, not from a different site. The server and client must cooperate to thwart this attack.
>
> In a common anti-XSRF technique, the application server [backend] **sends a randomly generated authentication token in a cookie. The client code reads the cookie and adds a custom request header with the token in all subsequent requests. The server compares the received cookie value to the request header value and rejects the request if the values are missing or don't match.**
>
> This technique is effective because all browsers implement the same origin policy. Only code from the website on which cookies are set can read the cookies from that site and set custom headers on requests to that site. That means only your application can read this cookie token and set the custom header. The malicious code on evil.com can't.

With that in mind, here's another quote from Angular HttpClient Docs which explains how you can implement it.

Taken from https://angular.io/guide/http#security-xsrf-protection:

> When performing HTTP requests, an interceptor reads a token from a cookie, by default XSRF-TOKEN, and sets it as an HTTP header, X-XSRF-TOKEN. Since only code that runs on your domain could read the cookie, the backend can be certain that the HTTP request came from your client application and not an attacker.
>
> By default, an interceptor sends this header on all mutating requests (POST, etc.) to relative URLs but not on GET/HEAD requests or on requests with an absolute URL.
>
> your server needs to set a token in a JavaScript readable session cookie called XSRF-TOKEN on either the page load or the first GET request. On subsequent requests the server can verify that the cookie matches the X-XSRF-TOKEN HTTP header, and therefore be sure that only code running on your domain could have sent the request. The token must be unique for each user and must be verifiable by the server; this prevents the client from making up its own tokens. Set the token to a digest of your site's authentication cookie with a salt for added security.

Key points to take note would be:

1. When the angular app is loaded, it should make an API call first to your backend to retrieve an authentication token that is saved as a cookie that with the name "XSRF-TOKEN". Probably somewhere on root component (app.component.ts) ngOnInit() sounds like a good place.
2. By default, the authentication token will be automatically injected in the http header on all mutating requests such as POST. (Take note of this though, it is undocumented: [Angular 6 does not add X-XSRF-TOKEN header to http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510998/angular-6-does-not-add-x-xsrf-token-header-to-http-request)). Unless you return a custom-named cookie, then you have to use Angular's HttpClientXsrfModule.
3. With that in mind, your ASP.NET Web API should also be validating the XSRF-TOKEN as it receives requests.

With regards to your second question, cookie hijacking is done via XSS.

> XSS vulnerabilities generally occur when an application takes user input and outputs it to a page without validating, encoding or escaping it.

Angular by default sanitizes inputs for  tags. However, this is provided you do things "the angular way". If you use third-party libs, such as jQuery, to manipulate the DOM instead of using Angular's renderer2 module, you might lose this protections.

Taken from: https://angular.io/guide/security#xss:

> In the same way, if you interact with other libraries that manipulate the DOM, you likely won't have the same automatic sanitization as with Angular interpolations. Avoid directly interacting with the DOM and instead use Angular templates where possible.
>
> For cases where this is unavoidable, use the built-in Angular sanitization functions. Sanitize untrusted values with the DomSanitizer.sanitize method and the appropriate SecurityContext.

To increase security, you should also sanitize any mutating requests (such as PUT or POST) in your backend.

It is difficult to provide you with code examples because your question seem to be a more theory-based question.

I hope you will take a read on those links that I have hyperlinked above. They are definitely more detailed and well-explained. I hope it will at least point you in the right direction of what to get started on.

Comment: This is such a great explanation. So just to confirm the XSS, there is no way the hacker could get the user cookie if the cookie is kept safe (not displayed in the DOM) correct?

Comment: yep. You should also use HTTPS to prevent man-in-the-middle attack that would allow attackers to view your token