# configure CSRF between Angular 8 and springboot 2.2.1

Tags: angular, spring-boot, google-chrome, spring-security

I have just done migration from Angular 5 to Angular 8 but a problem appeared with my CSRF configuration.

According to an old issue, I have changed my spring security csrf configuration ([Angular 6 does not add X-XSRF-TOKEN header to http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510998/angular-6-does-not-add-x-xsrf-token-header-to-http-request)) :

```
final CookieCsrfTokenRepository tokenRepository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
tokenRepository.setCookiePath("/");
http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(tokenRepository);
```

When I use my front, my post query on spring API return 403 error with Chrome 79. I suppose it's related to header "X-XSRF-TOKEN" which is not present in my Angular 8 query.

How can I correct this error?

Answer (score 0):

According to an other issue :

**"By default, an interceptor sends this cookie on all mutating requests (POST, etc.) to relative URLs but not on GET/HEAD requests or on requests with an absolute URL."**

So, the solution is to uses relative URL and not absolute url in all API call.

Thanks @G. Tricot for your help :D